# Knexjs obfuscate database and tables name

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, obfuscation, knex.js

I was looking for a javascript library to manage mysql databases and found Knexjs well suited for my needs, but i don't want to make database and tables readable from js source files.

On the other side I can't just obfuscate js since names would be unreadable for the application too.

Any idea out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Let's back up a minute. What are you trying to do here? Where is this Javascript code running, and how does it have access to MySQL?

Comment: @duskwuff in my setup it would run merely client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table names in strings loaded from environment variables.